# Array subscripts in VBA- Can anyone explain this?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Please find attached a screenshot of a small test program that I wrote to illustrate a confusion I am having. The text in <> is inputted by me to explain the error I am getting.

[image]

The MsgBox was created to make the program stay in a break mode so that I can see what the values were.

Here is the code. (I had discarded the earlier version but the values should still be same)

```
Sub test()
Dim Test1()
Dim Test2()

'values hardcoded in the sheet from where this macro is launched
'Cells(7,4) = 1
'Cells(7,5) = 2
'Cells(7,6) = 3
'Cells(7,7) = 4
'Cells(7,8) = 5
'Cells(7,9) = 6
'Cells(7,10) = 7


Set Rng1 = Range(Cells(7, 4), Cells(7, 10))
Test1 = Rng1.Value2
ReDim Test2(4)
Test2 = Rng1.Value2
MsgBox ("This was a test program")

End Sub
```

My Questions

1. It is a single row array - so why does Excel take it as a two dimensional array?
2. Normally the first row and column start from 0 i.e. zero. So why do I have to use 1 for accessing the values picked by the array? Or why does row 0 and column 0 give an error?
3. Even if `Redim` statement forces it to have 4 values, why is it picking up the fifth value? Does this mean we need not worry about Redimensioning the array if more values are likely to be encountered and Excel will always do the needful?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Seems like when you initialize your array from a range it starts from 1.  To help you visualize the structure of your arrays, select `View` from the "Menu" toolbar and then `Show Local Variables`.  In this new window you will see all the active variables and their values.  Pretty useful.  Last thing, when you navigate in an array, always use **[LBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445057(v=vs.60).aspx) and [UBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263396(v=vs.60).aspx)**

Comment: Thanks. I used 1 as the minimum range for iterations with the array but that was because that was the only thing that worked. Now I know the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are simply overwriting your array with the range you set as `Rng1`. After the code of

```
Test2 = Rng1.Value2
```

This means that your array is not the array you `ReDim`ed, but the array of values returned by Excel's `Value2` property, which is a 1 based 2D array, one value for each cell in `Rng1`.

So, yes, arrays, unless specified, are 0 based, but the array returned by the `Value2` property is 1 based when returned for a range of values. (If you call `Value2` on a single cell instead of an range of cells, you just get a Variant.)

Comment: Thanks. I think the distinction between 0 based and 1 based arrays is quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you get an array from a range, it will almost always be a two-dimensional array.  The exception to this is a range that is a single cell.

**EDIT#1**:

To verify the Ubounds and Lbounds, try running **MAIN** :

```
Sub SizeAndShape(ary)
    MsgBox LBound(ary, 1) & "-" & UBound(ary, 1) & vbCrLf & LBound(ary, 2) & "-" & UBound(ary, 2)
End Sub

Sub MAIN()
    Set Rng1 = Range(Cells(7, 4), Cells(7, 10))
    Test1 = Rng1.Value2
    Call SizeAndShape(Test1)
End Sub
```

Comment: The code is there in the image. Do you want me to post it still? Even if it is a 2 dimensional array, why does it not start with 0 as lower bound?

Comment: If you do not post the code, we cannot **Copy/Paste** it.  That slows us down.

Comment: @Peekay because cells (0,0) don't exist. They always start at 1,1

Comment: @mehow - I am talking about array counters not cell coordinates. Hope the code makes it clear

Comment: I think it makes it pretty clear. Still not sure why it does so though. Thanks mehow and Gary's Student for sparing the time and answering the question.

Comment: @mehow I think I now understood your point. Were you trying to say the array subscripts will be same as range subscripts?

Comment: @Peekay no. All I am saying is that if you assign a range to a 2d array it will always be 1 based instead of 0.