# VBA range to array - WHAT?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I am getting confused here, this code throws a subscript out of range error - i cannot see why

```
Public Sub Tester()

Dim Arr As Variant
Dim n As Long
Dim size As Integer
Dim width As Integer


Arr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L13:L20")


width = LBound(Arr)
size = UBound(Arr)
Debug.Print size


For n = 1 To 8
    Debug.Print Arr(n)
Next
End Sub
```

any help will be great - i hope Im overlooking something simple, but all the subscript out of range help on the net is so far not much use...

Comment: What line is causing you trouble ?

Comment: Arrays are often zero based. IE try "n = 0 to 7"

Comment: I notice you'r getting LBound and UBound, but not actually consuming them. Did you mean to use For `n = width to size` ?

Comment: sorry guys, so many iterations of this code, some minor typos, but yeah the solution is "Debug.Print Arr(n, 1)" - my bad, up to late, not enough sleep haha

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array subscripts in VBA- Can anyone explain this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689600/array-subscripts-in-vba-can-anyone-explain-this)

Answer (score 3):

When you convert a Range to a Variant/Array Excel always creates a 2-dimensional array, even for a single column. You need:

```
For n = 1 To 8
    Debug.Print Arr(n, 1)
Next
```

The array has dimensions (1 To 8, 1 To 1).

Comment: a great resource for catching things like this is the Locals window. I'm not sure if it's on by default, but setting break point and stepping through the code while keeping the locals window open as a reference helps cure all kinds of "why isn't this variable returning what I think it should" kinds of problems.

Comment: Yes, I used this to verify the array structure. It is available from the View menu.

Comment: @AndyG Sorry should have been more clear, my comment was more directed towards the OP.

Comment: @sous2817 I knew it was, I was just adding-to your recommendation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce the problem. It seems to be caused by VBA returning a 2D array instead of a 1D array. Basically, there is a dimension for rows and another for columns. You need to modify `Arr(n)` to `Arr(n, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Public Sub Tester()
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim size As Integer
    Dim width As Integer
    Arr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L13:L20")
    width = LBound(Arr)
    size = UBound(Arr)
    Debug.Print size
    For Each a In Arr
        Debug.Print a
    Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the values of a range's cells are manipulated as a two dimensional array in VBA. The first dimension is analogous to the row number, the second is analogous to the column number. Both are base 1.

So your code should be as follows:

```
Public Sub Tester()
    PrintRangeValues Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L13:L20")
End Sub

Public Sub PrintRangeValues(rngRange As Range)
    Dim vntRangeValues As Variant
    Dim lngRowCounter As Long
    Dim lngColCounter As Long

    vntRangeValues = rngRange.Cells.Value

    For lngRowCounter = 1 To rngRange.Rows.Count
        For lngColCounter = 1 To rngRange.Columns.Count
            Debug.Print vntRangeValues(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter)
        Next lngColCounter
    Next lngRowCounter
End Sub
```